# Find a substring using RegEx in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, command-line

```
'Open Source man Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./)

'Open source man Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 9)
```

I am following this : http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/8-string-advanced

could somebody explain them , I am unable to understand them.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats your question? What substring are you trying to find?

Comment: @Singleton aah!I am very sorry. please look at the link.

Comment: What did you not understand, the regex is just a character following a space.

Comment: @YuHao If I do understand , why I am gonna post here brother. :)

Comment: some example , they gonna clear :)

Comment: No, I mean what part did you not understand, the link you provide explains pretty well, so you need to specify exactly which part you don't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Monk clearly says

```
When the second parameter is present, it specifies the position 
in the string to begin the search.
```

The Master says :

```
"I'm not pleased with your question at all. Its unclear and there is no proof of effort"
```

Update

```
'Open Source man Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./) #=> only one parameter
'Open Source man Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 9) #=> 9 is the second parameter.
```

The Master says :

```
"There's nothing equal to paying attention to what you read and what you practice. 
Outside this there is no Ruby, there is no Java"
```

Comment: whats the 2nd parameter ?

Comment: what will be searched in the 1st case